# How to create a Custom Action that initiates a workflow inside a Document Set view

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I am working in a SharePoint Online environment and designing workflows and custom actions using SharePoint Designer.

I want to make a custom action that initiates the workflow. I have managed to make a 'View Custom Action'. My problem is that the button only shows within the Document Library main view.

I want to be able to only show the custom action from inside the document set (document set view).

Otherwise if this is not possible, I want to be able to only show the button in a filtered Document Library view, which only shows a specific content type and not in the 'All Documents View'.

Scenario:

Say I have 3 content types: Stage1, Stage2, Stage3
And 3 workflows: ApproveStage1, ApproveStage2, ApproveStage3

Option1 (most ideal): Inside Document Set view of Stage 1 have ApproveStage1 custom action, inside Document Set view of Stage 2 have ApproveStage2 custom action, etc..

Option 2 (if option 1 not possible): Not within the document sets, but within the view (in the document library) that filters by Content Type: Stage1, show ApproveStage1, on the view that filters by Content Type: Stage2, shows ApproveStage2, etc

Comment: Are you designing a 2010 or 2013 type workflow?

Comment: I am using Sharepoint 2010 for 'sub workflows' and a main Sharepoint 2013 workflow that is triggered by the custom action button and subsequently calls the sub workflows.

Comment: Interesting thing to note how do you implement "Custom Action button" to trigger the main workflow? 
Have you saved the "Manual Start Option" Link for the button click to trigger the main workflow?

Comment: I did in the Sharepoint Designer, and there is only an option for the View Ribbon. There's also an option for List Item menu, but when going into the Document set, I do not see it in the menu (or anywhere for that matter)